# How to write Int value 1 to peripheral characteristic

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

```
data: Int = 1
```

```
func writeOutgoingValue(data: Int){
    var myData = data
    var newData = Data(bytes: &myData, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: myData))
    print(myData)
    print(newData)
    if let LED_Peripheral = LED_Peripheral {
        if let LED_Char = LED_Char {
            LED_Peripheral.writeValue(newData, for: LED_Char, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to send integer 1 and 0 and I can't get it into Data format.

Or anything to work.

When I send int 1, I get 8 bytes, but sending 0 produces 0 bytes.

Curiously, I have another version with a slider, incrementer, which works, if you set it on 1 or anything greater,

- a slider with a state var

This is the func for the slider app.

```
func writeOutgoingValue(data: Int){
        let data = withUnsafeBytes(of: data) { Data($0) }

        if let LED_Peripheral = LED_Peripheral {
            if let LED_Char = LED_Char {
                LED_Peripheral.writeValue( data, for: LED_Char, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, ... I found my errors. The writeOutgoing works ok.  I had troubles  in my didDiscover - services and characteristics.  Some items were missing.  Now, all the stuff about unwrapping a UInt8, I really don't get.  Line-by-line, is becoming kinda fun.  !

Answer (score 2):

Use Data([1]) to send a 1 that is 1 byte long